# Passing value on img src $_GET issue

Tags: php

I am passing values from the img src like this:

PageA:

```
<img src="watermark.php?fname=<?php echo $image; ?>" />
```

then I ge the value on pageB:

```
$fname = $_GET['fname'];

$watermark_img = $passed_fname;

...
```

For some reason no image is showing ... I'm I missing something here?

Here is pageB full code:

```
<?php  

$fname = $_GET['fname'];

$main_img = "Porsche_911_996_Carrera_4S.jpg"; // main big photo / picture
//$watermark_img    = "watermark.gif"; // use GIF or PNG, JPEG has no tranparency support
$watermark_img = $fname;
$padding        = 3; // distance to border in pixels for watermark image
$opacity        = 100;  // image opacity for transparent watermark

$watermark  = imagecreatefromgif($watermark_img); // create watermark
$image      = imagecreatefromjpeg($main_img); // create main graphic

if(!$image || !$watermark) die("Error: main image or watermark could not be loaded!");


$watermark_size     = getimagesize($watermark_img);
$watermark_width    = $watermark_size[0];  
$watermark_height   = $watermark_size[1];  

$image_size     = getimagesize($main_img);  
$dest_x         = $image_size[0] - $watermark_width - $padding;  
$dest_y         = $image_size[1] - $watermark_height - $padding;


// copy watermark on main image
imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, $opacity);


// print image to screen
header("content-type: image/jpeg");   
imagejpeg($image);  
imagedestroy($image);  
imagedestroy($watermark);  

?>
```

Comment: Is `pageB == watermark.php` ? Is `$fname == $passed_fname` ? How do you return an image from `watermark.php` ?

Comment: I don't see `$passed_fname` or `$image` being defined anywhere. More code!

Comment: If you are using your php code serve the image, you also need to output the (binary) img data directly + setting the correct header(mime-type) - But you surely need to provide more info/code/context.

Comment: I have added all the code for pageB.

Comment: What debugging have you done?  Have you gone directly to the page to see the output?  Is PHP error reporting enabled?  Have you checked the logs?  So on, so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `$image` contains some *special* characters?

Try to use PHP **[`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)** function:

```
<img src="watermark.php?fname=<?php echo urlencode($image); ?>/>
```

And the, on the second page:

```
$fname = urldecode($_REQUEST['fname']);
```

Comment: If you use htmlentities, you only have to worry about it on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

If the value you pass on $fname is just the name, you might need to specify the full path.

```
$watermark_img = '/PATH_TO_THE_IMAGE/'.$fname;
```

Comment: $fname already contains the full path plus filename ... http://mydomain.com/images/myimage.png

Answer (score 0):

Try the watermark PHP directly from the address bar, then view source. If there is any output before you set the jpeg header, the browser will be unable to deal with it. You might have something like

> Error line 3443234
>
> JPEGIMAGECODE

That first line makes it an invalid image.